# GET params as string array if one value

Tags: typescript, get, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pass a string array as a parameter for a GET call:

```
// One value
param: filters=Something
value: filters: 'Something'

// Multiple values
param: filters=Something&filters=Something else
value: filters: [ 'Something', 'Something else' ]
```

The problem is that when I pass one value in the param the code thinks it passes a string, when I pass more then one value I get the string array.

I have tried stuff like Array.from etc, but then it just creates an array from the string:

```
['S', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

I need a way to force single values to be read as a String array. Is there something to do just that?

Edit:

I get the query, I need the filter values to filter the results and send them back. When there is one value in the filter parameter, it sees that as a string and chops it up. I need/want it to be one array, with one string value.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you've said:

> The question is not how I can create the query, but how to get a string array from the parameters even if it is just one value.

You loop through the query string parameters and build an array as you go if you've already seen the parameter at least once before:

```js
function getParameters(query)/*: Map<String,String> */ {
  const m = new Map/*<String,String>*/();
  for (const part of query.split("&")) {
    let [key, value] = part.split("=");
    key = decodeURIComponent(key); // People commonly miss out this bit
    vale = decodeURIComponent(value);
    if (m.has(key)) {
      let current = m.get(key);
      if (Array.isArray(current)) {
        current.push(value);
      } else {
        m.set(key, [current, value]);
      }
    } else {
      m.set(key, value);
    }
  }
  return m;
}

const query1 = "filters=Something&foo=bar";
const query2 = "foo=bar&filters=Something&filters=Something%20else";

console.log("query1's params:", [...getParameters(query1).entries()]);

console.log("query2's params:", [...getParameters(query2).entries()]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Alternately, if you *always* want an array for a particular parameter, you check the key and branch in that case:

```js
const arrayParams = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
  filters: true
});
function getParameters(query)/*: Map<String,String> */ {
  const m = new Map/*<String,String>*/();
  for (const part of query.split("&")) {
    let [key, value] = part.split("=");
    key = decodeURIComponent(key); // People commonly miss out this bit
    vale = decodeURIComponent(value);
    if (arrayParams[key]) {
      // Array parameter
      if (m.has(key)) {
        m.get(key).push(value);
      } else {
        m.set(key, [value]);
      }
    } else {
      // Non-array parameter, may or may not have multiple values (or maybe you take the last, etc.)
      if (m.has(key)) {
        let current = m.get(key);
        if (Array.isArray(current)) {
          current.push(value);
        } else {
          m.set(key, [current, value]);
        }
      } else {
        m.set(key, value);
      }
    }
  }
  return m;
}

const query1 = "filters=Something&foo=bar";
const query2 = "foo=bar&filters=Something&filters=Something%20else";

console.log("query1's params:", [...getParameters(query1).entries()]);

console.log("query2's params:", [...getParameters(query2).entries()]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the OP, I don't have access to the other system so I am using Postman for testing. It does create the string array when there are more then 1 value for a name.

Comment: @MarkvanTurnhout - I'm not sure why that's relevant? You're asking a question about how to do something in TypeScript, right? (And I don't see anything about Postman in the question.)

Comment: The question is not how I can create the query, but how to get a string array from the parameters even if it is just one value.

Comment: @MarkvanTurnhout - You mean the opposite of the answer above? Your starting point is a query string?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't explain it correctly. I get the query, and I need to get the values(filters) from the query. The problem is when it is just one value it thinks it is a string and creates an array with all individual chars. I just need one array, with one string value.

Comment: @MarkvanTurnhout - Got you now, I've updated the answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping it could be like a setting or something, but this should work to!

Comment: @MarkvanTurnhout - No worries. I should note that there's probably an open source library (or something provided by TypeScript) that handles gathering query string parameters for you, so you might look for that rather than rolling your own as with the above... :-) Happy coding!